# How do I install jdk on SUSE Linux with ansible?

Tags: suse, zypper, ansible, jdk

I need to install java on one of my VMs running SUSE Linux using ansible.

Below is the playbook code I am using:

```
- name: Download Java
  become_user: "{{user}}"
  command: "wget -q -O {{java_archive}} --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' {{download_url}} creates={{java_archive}}"

- name: Fix ownership
  become_user: "{{user}}"
  file: state=directory path={{java_name}} owner={{user}} group={{user}} recurse=yes

- zypper: name={{download_folder}}/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.rpm become_user={{user}} state=present

- name: Clean up
  become_user: "{{user}}"
  file: state=absent path={{java_archive}}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the installer needs some interactions while installing. How do I automate that? Or there is some other way to achieve this?

[image: interaction screen without ansible]

As requested in comments, following message appears when I try to install without ansible.

Comment: What are those needed interactions?

Comment: It is throwing an error in XML format with some prompts tags asking questions like Continue?, Abort, retry, ignore? etc.

[link](http://pastebin.com/4KM0Ab37) here is the link to the output that I have received (Raw unedited/unformatted)

Comment: Please capture the interaction prompts on a real shell (without ansible) and put then into your question. You probably have to do some work before you can run this playbook.

Answer (score 1):

From `ansible-doc zypper`:

```
- oldpackage
        Adds `--oldpackage' option to `zypper'. Allows to downgrade packages
        with less side-effects than force. This is implied as soon as a
        version is specified as part of the package name.
        (Choices: yes, no)[Default: no]
```

Try with `oldpackage=yes` and if it doesn't help you could use the more aggressive `force=yes` option.